# Prevent data load which already loaded previous in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my angular apps "/" url load 40 items, and i use pagination for load more 40 items when scroll down to bottom. And when I go any items detail page like "/detail/XXXXXXXX", its working well.

My problem is, when i return to "/" from detail page, my previously loaded data gone.Since, I back to "/", angular load root template and load again first 40 items.

How can I prevent reloading previously loaded data?

Comment: I see what you are saying .. $scope gets reset .. because you binded controller to html right so it is calling the api again .. when you redirected Update your routes and controller coding .. i can help you

Comment: yes, your are right. But, how can I solve it?

Comment: You need to Stop calling api while you calling the root .

Comment: so how to load my data first time?

Comment: can you pls update your code where i can tell you all the story how first time and then?

Comment: Yes, obviously. If you want... :)
For Help, this is my index route:
.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "/static/js/views/FrontPage.html",
    controller: "FrontController",
    resolve: {
        list_data: function (AppsService) {
            return AppsService.custom_query('/api?language=' + CheckCurrentLanguage());
        }
    },
    reloadOnSearch: false
})

Comment: and this is my detail route:
.when("/detail/:id", {
    templateUrl: "/static/js/views/DetailPage.html",
    controller: "DetailController",
    resolve: {
        detail_data: function ($route, AppsService) {
            var detail_id = $route.current.params.id;
            return AppsService.get(detail_id);
        }
    },
    reloadOnSearch: false
})

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**

You can use [ui-router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) to control multiple views in your app

**Second Solution**

Use absolute popup div with **ng-include** to load item details template and you can define custom route location for show detail box (I use)

Comment: Hi MBN, can you describe more to do it please? How can i define custom route?